# UML Class Diagram Multiplicity and ER Diagrams Cardinality

Tags: database, uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram, erd

I have a simple question about the multiplicity of the class diagrams and the cardinality of the ER diagrams. They are confusing me on how to choose them. Whether should I choose them from the concept of one instance or the whole system.

For example:
A User can create and have many profiles. And These profiles can have only one user. (One to Many)
However in general (in the whole system), Profiles can have many users other than this particular user. (Many to Many)

so my question, when i am designing class and ER diagrams should i take it from the perspective of one instance (one user) like the first one or from the whole system perspective. that many users can have many profiles and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A User can create and have many profiles. And These profiles can have only one user. (One to Many)

The class diagram can be :

[image]

The diagram indicates a given *User* can have any positive or null number of *Profile*, and a given *Profile* is for one and only one *User*.

That means an instance of *Profile* cannot exist without an associated instance of *User* so the relation can be a composition (when an instance of *User* disappears its *Profile*s disappear too) :

[image]

> However in general (in the whole system), Profiles can have many users other than this particular user. (Many to Many)

The previous diagram is still the right one, it makes no assumption on the total number of instances of *User* and *Profile*.

You can show example of instances through a object diagram :

[image]

---

From your remark :

> i will have two classes one named User and one named Modules So Users can enroll into modules, So in that way it will be many to many right? Many users can enroll into modules while modules can have many users, is that right? or should it be also using only one instance? Like A user can enroll into many modules, and these modules can only have one user (one instance)

Except if the module is dedicated/created for only one given user which is very less probable in that case you have many to many, so the multiplicity is "*" in both sides.

Comment: thank you so much. I have another example about users enrolling into modules,
so i will have two classes one named User and one named Modules
So Users can enroll into modules,  So in that way it will be many to many right? 

Many users can enroll into modules while modules can have many users, is that right? or should it be also using only one instance? Like A user can enroll into many modules, and these modules can only have one user (one instance) or am u confused between both examples?

Comment: @JackWilson is it through an other question ?

Comment: @JackWilson yes that time it is many to many, so "*" on both side for the multiplicities

Comment: @JackWilson I also edited my answer to add an object diagram

Comment: @JackWilson Please edit your question rather than add questions to comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!
So for clarification, it is one to many when it is something specific to that class like the profiles belongs to the user in that way i have to deal with it like an instance not the whole system and when it is something general like a module which is for all users to join it will be many to many not just an instance of a user joining the module?

Comment: @JackWilson, not exactely, it is not about 'general' or something like that, in UML you have to think about how it is for instances of classes (when the association is between instances, can be defined at class level e.g. *static*). So on each side (if not directional) for a given instance what are the min/max number of associated instances on the other side, when 0..infinite it is noted 0..* or just  *

Comment: so can i say that the relation between the user and the modules is static while between the user and the profile is directional? that why in the first one between the user and the module i treated it as a group of instances and between the user and the profile a single instance?

Comment: @JackWilson it is directional when one side does not know the other side. You did not treated as a group, I mean else the classes are not user and module but users and/or groups which is different. I think you try to complicate to much, in fact this is simple and logical